# Can't get a certain item from a webpage using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've created a script to scrape `name` and `email` address from a webpage. When I run my script I get the `name` accordingly but in case of `email` this is what I get `aeccdcd7cfc0eedadcc783cdc1dc80cdc1c3`. The string that I get instead of `email` changes every time I run the script.

[Website link](https://www.seafoodsource.com/supplier-directory/Tri-Cor-Flexible-Packaging-Inc)

I've tried so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.seafoodsource.com/supplier-directory/Tri-Cor-Flexible-Packaging-Inc"

res = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
name = soup.select_one("[class$='-supplier-view-main-container'] > h1").text
email = soup.select_one("[class='__cf_email__']").get("data-cfemail")
print(f'{"Name: "}{name}\n{"Email: "}{email}')
```

Current output:

```
Name: Tri-Cor Flexible Packaging Inc
Email: aeccdcd7cfc0eedadcc783cdc1dc80cdc1c3
```

Expected output:

```
Name: Tri-Cor Flexible Packaging Inc
Email: bryan@tri-cor.com
```

> PS I'm not after any solution related to any browser simulator, as in selenium.

***How can I get that email from that page using requests?***

Comment: Have you confirmed that the email is actually there in the data you get? E.g, save res.text to file and examine it in an editor.

Comment: Have you tried snooping with e.g. telerik fiddler when opening the page in a browser to see how the email address is retrieved from the server? And then emulate the headers/parameters/data in your requests GET.

Comment: email protected?

Comment: This is what you get without using a js browser or driver `<b>Contact email: </b> <a href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#b2d0c0cbd3dcf2c6c0db9fd1ddc09cd1dddf"><span class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="5f3d2d263e311f2b2d36723c302d713c3032">[email&#160;protected]</span></a>`

Comment: Read [Email Protection](https://www.seafoodsource.com/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#b2d0c0cbd3dcf2c6c0db9fd1ddc09cd1dddf)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513190/cf-hash-attribute-and-script-mysteriously-added-to-mailto-links

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to decode the email.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def cfDecodeEmail(encodedString):
    r = int(encodedString[:2],16)
    email = ''.join([chr(int(encodedString[i:i+2], 16) ^ r) for i in range(2, len(encodedString), 2)])
    return email

url = "https://www.seafoodsource.com/supplier-directory/Tri-Cor-Flexible-Packaging-Inc"

res = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
name = soup.select_one("[class$='-supplier-view-main-container'] > h1").text
email = cfDecodeEmail(soup.select_one("[class='__cf_email__']").get("data-cfemail"))
print(f'{"Name: "}{name}\n{"Email: "}{email}')
```

Output:

```
Name: Tri-Cor Flexible Packaging Inc
Email: bryan@tri-cor.com
```

Answer (score 8):

*The short answer is that you have to decode the email string, because it is being obfuscated.*

**Below is the reason why you have to decode the email string that you obtained from [seafoodsource.com](https://www.seafoodsource.com).**

The website [seafoodsource.com](https://www.seafoodsource.com) is using Cloudflare, which is a U.S. company that provides customer with website security, DDoS mitigation and other services.

I determined that the site was using Cloudflare by pinging seafoodsource.com, which returned the IP address 104.24.19.99.  According to ARIN (American Registry for Internet Numbers) this IP address belongs to the netblock 104.16.0.0 - 104.31.255.255, which is registered to [Cloudflare](https://search.arin.net/rdap/?query=104.24.19.99).

The string *cf_email* in your soup is also an indication that the email address is being protected by Cloudflare(CF). Another indication is this warning [message](https://www.seafoodsource.com/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#bfddcdc6ded1ffcbcdd692dcd0cd91dcd0d2), which displayed when you click the protected link when viewing the page source.

Cloudflare Email Address Obfuscation helps in spam prevention by hiding email addresses that appear on the target website from email harvesters and other bots, but the email is visible to normal site visitors.

Under this protection an email address become a hex encoded series of bytes of variable length, depending on the length of the email address.

It is worth noting that this encoding method is not designed to securely encrypt an email address, because it is cryptographically weak, but it is ***only*** designed to confuse non-intelligent web scrapers that are searching for mailto: links within the HTML code. In other words this encoding method is used to obfuscate an email address, but not completely enforce its confidentiality.

> The encoded email address in your question is:
>
> *aeccdcd7cfc0eedadcc783cdc1dc80cdc1c3*
>
> The first byte of this email address is ae or hexadecimal 0xae. This byte is a key used to encrypt and decrypt the remaining bytes by bitwise XORing the key with each subsequent byte.
>
> For instance:
>
> 0xae ^ 0xcc is hexadecimal 62, which translates to **b** in ASCII
>
> 0xae ^ 0xdc is hexadecimal 72, which translates to **r** in ASCII
>
> 0xae ^ 0xd7 is hexadecimal 79, which translates to **y** in ASCII
>
> 0xae ^ 0xcf is hexadecimal 61, which translates to **a** in ASCII
>
> 0xae ^ 0xc0 is hexadecimal 6e, which translates to **n** in ASCII
>
> This spells **bryan**, which is the first part of the decoded email address.
>
> The bitwise XORing is happening in this code:
>
> chr(int(encoded_string[i:i+2], 16) ^ base_16)

Let me explain further:

> The first byte of the encoding string is the cipher key, which in this case is ae or 0xae.
>
> If we convert 0xae to decimal it becomes 174.
>
> When we convert the next byte 0xcc to decimal it becomes 204.
>
> Let's convert these decimals using the bitwise operator ^.
>
> ^ Bitwise Exclusive XOR
>
> Returns the result of bitwise XOR of two integers.

```
first_byte = 174 # ae
second_byte = 204 # cc
xor_decimal = first_byte ^ second_byte 
print (xor_decimal) 
# outputs 
98
```

> Let's convert these decimals to hexadecimals (base-16). We can use the built-in function "hex" in Python to accomplish this.

```
first_byte = 174 # ae
second_byte = 204 # cc
xor_decimal = first_byte ^ second_byte 
print (hex)xor_decimal)
# outputs 
62
```

> As I previously mentioned hexadecimal 62, translates to **b** in ASCII
>
> Let's look at the next byte iteration in the encoded string.

```
first_byte = 174 # ae
next_byte = 220 # dc
xor_decimal = first_byte ^ next_byte 
print (hex)xor_decimal)
# outputs 
72
```

> As I previously mentioned hexadecimal 72, translates to **r** in ASCII
>
> I feel that it's relevant to show how to convert a hex string to a decimal.

```
 # without the 0x prefix
 decimal = int('ae', 16)
 print (decimal)
 # outputs
 174 

 # with the 0x prefix
 decimal = int('0xae', 0)
 print (decimal)
 # outputs
 174
```

**ASCII Text to Hex conversion for the obfuscated email address:**

> ASCII email address: bryan@tri-cor.com
>
> Hex email address: 62 72 79 61 6e 40 74 72 69 2d 63 6f 72 2e 63 6f 6d

**We can use the built-in function *bytearray* in Python to decode this hex string:**

```
hex_string = '62 72 79 61 6e 40 74 72 69 2d 63 6f 72 2e 63 6f 6d'
ascii_conversion = bytearray.fromhex(hex_string).decode()
print (ascii_conversion)
# outputs
bryan@tri-cor.com
```

**ASCII Text to Decimal conversion for the obfuscated email address:**

> ASCII email address: bryan@tri-cor.com
>
> Decimal email address: 98 114 121 97 110 64 116 114 105 45 99 111 114 46 99 111 109

**If we prepend decimal 174, which was *ae* in the obfuscated string to the head of the decimal email address:**

> Decimal email address: 174 98 114 121 97 110 64 116 114 105 45 99 111 114 46 99 111 109
>
> ASCII email address: ®bryan@tri-cor.com

*It looks like ® was the ASCII character used as the cipher key for the obfuscated string in your question.*

> I would be remiss if I did not mention binary numbers and XOR operations.

**First byte conversions:**

- hex number: ae
- decimal number: 174
- hexadecimals (base-16): 98
- binary number: 10101110
- ascii text: ®

**Second byte conversions:**

- hex number: cc
- decimal number: 204
- hexadecimals (base-16): 62
- binary number: 11001100
- ascii text: b

> We can perform the same ^ Bitwise Exclusive XOR operations with the binary numbers above:

```
# the notation 0b in front of the number is used to express that the value is 
# a binary literal
first_byte_binary = 0b10101110
second_byte_binary = 0b11001100
xor_binary = first_byte_binary ^ second_byte_binary
print (bin(xor_binary))
# outputs
0b1100010

print (xor_binary)
# outputs 
98

print (hex(xor_binary))
# outputs
0x62

ascii_conversion = bytearray.fromhex(hex(xor_binary)[2:]).decode()
print (ascii_conversion)
# outputs
b
```

**Here is how to decode Cloudflare obfuscated email addresses.**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.seafoodsource.com/supplier-directory/Tri-Cor-Flexible-Packaging-Inc"

raw_html = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html.text,'lxml')

company_information = []

def get_company_name(soup):
  company_name = soup.find('li', {'class': 'active'}).text
  company_information.append(company_name)
  return

def decode_cloudflare_protected_email(encoded_string):
    # converting the encoding string to int base 16
    base_16 = int(encoded_string[:2], 16)
    decoded_email = ''.join([chr(int(encoded_string[i:i+2], 16) ^ base_16) for i in range(2, len(encoded_string), 2)])
    company_information.append(decoded_email)
    return

get_company_name(soup)

encoded_email = soup.select_one("[class='__cf_email__']").get("data-cfemail")
decode_cloudflare_protected_email(encoded_email)

print (company_information)
# outputs
['Tri-Cor Flexible Packaging Inc', 'bryan@tri-cor.com']
```

If you are interesting in exploring XOR encryption more than I would suggest looking at the [xortool](https://github.com/hellman/xortool), which is a Github project by Aleksei Hellman.